# An (easy) function to see whether or not it is complex differentiable (and Partial derivatives.)

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose we consider a function
$$
  f(z) =f(x,y) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   1 & \text{if $z=0$} \\
                                   0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

So this is just a function that is identically $0$ on the whole plane except at the origin. Now I think this function is not holomorphic about $z=0$ and I have thought about these $3$ reasons:

*Reason 1:* This function is not continuous at $z=0$ hence not holomorphic.
*Reason 2:* $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$ does not exist from 'any directions towards $z=0$' and so by definition this is not holomorphic about $z=0.$ (since we, informally speaking, have the situation of $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}$ here.)
*Reason 3:* If we suppose $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and compute the partial derivatives, we see $u_x$ and $u_y$ do not exist at $(0,0)$ and hence by contrapositive of Cauchy Riemann Equation, we must deduce this function is not holomorphic at $z=0.$ (The reason why it doesn't exist is similar to Reason 2.)

I am now just curious wether or not my reasons are valid or not, in particular, I feel the most unsure about Reason 1, could someone please advise me?

Many thanks!

Comment: A holomorphic function is (infinitely) differentiable, so it has to be continuous. So yes, Reason 1 is valid, as well as 2 and 3.

Comment: Reason 2 and 3 are direct consequences of reason 1, which makes reason 1 all the more correct (and in my opinion elegant as well).